# Mesmos números no par chave-valor de um array, porém aleatório

Tags: php, array

Supondo que eu tenha um *array* desta forma:

```
array(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
```

Estou tentando fazer uma forma de obter como resultado, um *array* com os pares chave-valor, mas de forma aleatória sem que os pares sejam iguais. Por exemplo:

**Válido**

```
array(
    10 => 14,
    11 => 12,
    12 => 15,
    13 => 10,
    14 => 11,
    15 => 13
)
```

**Não válido**

```
array(
    10 => 14,
    11 => 11, // Não pode
    12 => 15,
    13 => 10,
    14 => 12,
    15 => 13
)
```

O segundo não é válido pois a segunda posição possui o mesmo valor **11** tanto na chave quanto no valor.

Minha tentativa foi essa:

```
$result = array();

$array = array(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15);
$copy = array(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15);

foreach ($array as $a) {
    $b = array_rand($copy, 1);

    while (!in_array($copy[$b], $result)) {
        if ($a != $copy[$b])
            $result[$a] = $copy[$b];
        else
            $b = array_rand($copy, 1);
    }

    unset($copy[$b]);
}
```

Muitas vezes dá certo, mas tem hora que ele não sai do **while**, aí atinge o tempo máximo de execução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meu desenvolvimento foi da seguinte maneira :

```
$array = array(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20);
if(count($array) > 1){
    do{

        $flip = array_flip($array);
        $newArray = array();

        $reset = false;
        foreach ($flip as $key => $value){
            $range = $flip;                 # COPIA FLIP PARA O RANGE A SER TRATADO
            unset($range[$key]);                # REMOVE A CHAVE ATUAL DO RANGE

            if(!$range){                       # VERIFICA SE O ARRAY ESTA VAZIO
                $reset = true;                 # - PODE OCORRER NA ULTIMA CHAVE
                break;                        # - RESETA PARA INICIAR DO 0
            }

            $range = array_keys($range);        # CRIA UM ARRAY APENAS COM OS VALORES DISPONIVEIS
            $rand = rand(0, count($range)-1);   # SORTEIA UM VALOR A SER COPIADO
            $value = $range[$rand];          # CAPTURA O VALOR
            $newArray[$key] = $value;        # SETA O NOVO ARRAY COM A CHAVE E O VALOR SORTIADO
            unset($flip[$value]);               # REMOVE O VALOR SORTIADO DAS PROXIMAS ESCOLHAS
        }
    }while($reset);
}
```

O código já esta explicado, mas só para destacar, as chances são baixas mas poderia ocorrer de todos os números serem sorteados, e o ultimo valor restante fosse o mesmo da ultima key, assim gerando erro. Pois isso o uso do `do{}while($reset);`

Comment: Perfeito, deu tudo certo nos teste. Obrigado!